# serving downloadable files from original domain

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have my domain on 1&1 and it's redirecting to my heroku app. 
When I was hosting the app on 1&1 I was able to download other files in separate folders using the same url with the subfolder as path.

```
www.mywebsite.com/mysubfolder/file
```

my app on heroku is using express to serve my app itself and any static files related to my app like css and js files.

**App.js**

```
const publicPath = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'));
app.use('/public', publicPath);
app.get('*', IndexController.renderAll);
```

**IndexController.js**

```
const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../index.html');

exports.renderAll = (req, res, next)=>{
    res.sendFile(indexPath);
}
```

What i'm trying to find out is how can I allow for my files that are still on 1&1 under www.mywebsite.com/subfolder to be accessed for downloadable purposes using something like I did before. www.mywebsite.com/mysubfolder/file

apart from adding a subfolder to my heroku public folder is there anyway to acess them from 1&1 ?

Comment: Did you consider using a storage service like Amazon S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)? About your question, you might try to pipe the file from the other server to your response.

Comment: How would I pipe the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this function:

```
const request = require('request');

(req, res) => {
    const url = 'https://1&1.com';
    request.get(url + req.originalUrl).pipe(res);
}
```